# ElasticSearch indices become empty randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, searchkick

ElasticSearch indices become empty randomly, but most of times, it occurs after deploying the application built with Rails.

Here some info about ElastiSearch:

[curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty'](http://pastebin.com/XmGLg0S1)

[curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'](https://gist.github.com/Rodrigora/d4cb9620c0f83e9e6393)

[curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'](https://gist.github.com/Rodrigora/f083dfbb42ab3fd8aee1)

Recurring stack trace in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log:

```
[2014-11-21 16:46:05,204][WARN ][cluster.service          ] [Joe Cartelli] failed to reconnect to node [Joe Cartelli][AvwiuMNRRUywfTyii7gI0A][ip-172-31-19-137][inet[/172.31.19.137:9300]]
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Joe Cartelli][inet[/172.31.19.137:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:727)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:656)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:624)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:146)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$ReconnectToNodes.run(InternalClusterService.java:518)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.19.137:9300
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    ... 3 more
```

**Obs: The 172.31.19.137 IP address is the private IP of EC2 instance on AWS.**

**EDIT:**

The erros stills occurs and I had new information about the issue.

After 'data gone', I looked at `elasticsearch.log` and [Stack Trace](http://pastebin.com/XmGLg0S1) was printed many times. I don't know if this error happens before or after the 'data gone'. Note that the index name is `products_production_20141130122307375`.

Running the command to list all Elasticsearch indexes `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`, printed the products index but with different number: `products_production_20141XXXXXXXXXX` (I didn't wrote down the exact number).

So, why the name of indexes weren't same?

It's possible, for some strange reason for me, Rails/Searchkick recreate the index and lose the data?

**EDIT 2**

The problem occurs after ElasticSearch log this:

```
[2014-12-02 00:47:10,698][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Tyr] [products_production_20141202004040313] update_mapping [product] (dynamic)
[2014-12-02 00:58:02,173][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Tyr] [products_production_20141202005801257] creating index, cause [api], shards [5]/[1], mappings [_default_]
[2014-12-02 00:58:46,064][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Tyr] [products_production_20141202005801257] update_mapping [product] (dynamic)
[2014-12-02 00:58:48,371][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Tyr] [products_production_20141202004040313] deleting index
```

It looks like that `searchkick` recreates the index and loses the products of older index.

Comment: Where is the data stored? It sounds like your EC2 instance goes away, and the data is wiped there. Separately, make sure your Rails application does not wipe out the indices (unrelated to the connectivity, which suggests the former issue).

Comment: no @pickypg, my EC2 instance is attached to EBS volume

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: I don't know what's with the downvotes, but I also don't know why it's happening. Since it happens with the Rails application deployment, I suspect people want to see more details related to it. I'm still assuming that it wipes the data for some reason.

Comment: anyway @Rodrigo can elaborate more over the question, but that isn't a reason for a downvote!

Comment: @Rodrigo, could you post more info please, config file at least.

Comment: Do you connecting via `127.0.0.1` or some external ip? How much elasticsearch nodes do you have?

Comment: @ole, I connecting via ```127.0.0.1```. Only one node with 5 shards

Comment: Node is trying to connect the cluster on external ip.  You should set `network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1`
`network.host: 127.0.0.1` in the `elasticsearch.yml` config file. That should help.

Comment: Thanks @ole, I already did this, but didn't solved the problema. It look like the ```searchkick``` gem is recreating the index, but I don't know why

Comment: @ole, look at my last edit please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this issue could be related to your problem:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/307